# How did the Allies communicate during World War II?

Tags: world-war-two, communication

I was wondering how the allied (America and England, since France was occupied by the Nazis) communicated securely with each other in 1943. I know that the [SIGSALY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSALY) existed, but I am most interested in how [Roosevelt's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franklin_D._Roosevelt) and [Churchill's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill) telegrams were encrypted. Did they use the British [Typex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typex) or the American [SIGABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABA)?

Comment: Totally mandatory reading material: [Neal Stephenson - Cryptonomicon](http://www.amazon.de/Cryptonomicon-Neal-Stephenson/dp/0060512806/ref=sr_1_1?s=books-intl-de&ie=UTF8&qid=1418291835&sr=1-1&keywords=neal+stephenson+cryptonomicon)

Comment: @tho I have issues with some of the techniques described in the book; particularly when they describe how they use white noise to encrypt a voice call... given a non trivial delay in the signal (IIRC it was a call from Australia to UK), I doubt the setup would have worked.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The communications between national leaders are *normally* conducted through the embassies.
I.e., Churchill would send a [Typex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typex)-encrypted telegram to the [British Embassy in Washington, DC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Embassy,_Washington), it is decrypted there, and delivered in person to the [White House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_House). Similarly, Roosevelt would send a [SIGABA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABA)-encrypted message to the [US Embassy in London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embassy_of_the_United_States,_London), it is decrypted there and delivered in person to [Number 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10_Downing_Street).
([Cold War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_War) required faster decision making, necessitating [Moscow-Washington hotline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow-Washington_hotline)).

The direct communications between the militaries were conducted via [Combined Cipher Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_Cipher_Machine) starting 1943-11-01.

The machine looked like a typewriter (all of them did, including [Enigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_machine)) and was operated by a technician.